# How to use MAT in eclipse to find memory leaks

Tags: android, eclipse, memory-leaks, eclipse-mat

I am a newbie on this topic so i researched about MAT on internet but the articles were quite  old,and there was something about creating a heap dump and manually converting the file into some other format etc etc.....but as soon as i click on heap dump i get this

[image]

so i am guessing that i don't need to convert it anymore or do i??

and i would like to ask that my app takes about 40-120 mb ram.the size keeps increasing due to memory leaks  how to find out which variable is causing it?can we even find out memory allocations for separate variables ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to convert it any more, hprof is more than enough to find memory leaks

In MAT you click on Histogram and dominator_tree menu. Both will show you list of runtime objects and respective size of retained heap. You can easily get start up point for code analysis based on retained heap size and get to the root of memory leak.

Also, if you click on leak suspects you will get list of problem suspects.

Comment: well thank you but since I was unable to find it using mat,I changed the entire structure of my code,nullifying the values whenever they are not required and that helped a lot... :D
also came to know that if Context is not nullified,the activity doesn't get destroyed which results in memory leaks....
Still having a few memory leaks but the amount has drastically reduced :D

Comment: I still need to know how to clear layouts ..will nullifying  them help ?

Comment: Absolutely, nullifying object after there use is good practice. Specially closing your JDBC Conn objects etc. If you still face any issue its always recommended to use some tolls like MAT to get the root cause. You can even you JConsole to see memory consumption of your application at run time. As its run time you will easily find when memory demand is higher and you can concentrate on particular functionality.

Comment: Thank you 
help needed here 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23568216/broadcast-is-never-received